# Strange behavior of gmtime_r

Tags: c, gcc, time

```
int main() {
    time_t *ptr;
    struct tm *dates;
    time(ptr);
    gmtime_r(ptr, dates);
    size_t a = 20; //<-- works with int
    return 0;
}
```

It fails with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. When I use `int` instead of `size_t` everything works fine. When I change `gmtime_r` to non-thread-safety `gmtime` it works too though I have to add declaration of pointer which `gmtime` will assign to. [Declaration of `gmtime_r`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime_r).

gcc version is 5.4.0, compile with `gcc -Wall -o a test.c`, 64-bit ubuntu.

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers in C are just that, they identify a location where data might be (or might not, in which case undefined behavior is the rule).

```
int main() {
    time_t ptr; // Actual storage for time_t
    struct tm dates; // Actual storage for struct tm
    time(&ptr); // Pointer to a time_t
    gmtime_r(&ptr, &dates); // Pointer to a time_t, pointer to a
    // struct tm
    size_t a = 20; //<-- works with int
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks! It seems that I have to have some practice with pointers and theoretical minimum too!

Answer (score 1):

Not strange at all; you need to allocate what `dates` points to, so `gmtime_r` can fill it.  And what `ptr` points to, so `time` can fill that.